# Swing : Component for displaying text Streaming Data

Tags: swing

I have a requirement where i need to display Streaming Data like  Bid , Ask , Last , Change values for the Stock Quote Symbols recievied from a third party server  in a Grid .

For this can i use a Jtable as the Data would be chnaging continously ??

Please share your views , thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, why not use a JTable for that matter. I guess that at some point you will have to create a SlidingWindow over your TableModel in order to avoid excessive data.

Here is a small demo example that shows one way to do it (the `Random` and `Timer` are just there to simulate the incoming data):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestStreamingDataTable {

    protected void initUI() {
        final Random random = new Random();
        final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] { "Bid", "Ask", "Last", "Change values", "Time" }, 0);
        final JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestStreamingDataTable.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.insertRow(0, new Object[] { random.nextInt(1000), random.nextInt(1000), random.nextInt(1000), random.nextInt(1000),
                        new Date() });
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestStreamingDataTable().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Great answer , thanks a lot Polet . my requirement is that , instead of inserting a new row , is it possible to update the row ??

Comment: @PreethiJain You can always use `setValueAt()` but you have to do it cell by cell. You would be better off with a your own table model class that extends `AbstractTableModel` implementing all the methods of `TableModel` and having some extra-methods to update one or several rows simultaneously. Those methods would then need to call the appropriate fireTableXXX methods provided by `AbstractTableModel`.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i can manage with setValueAt . thanks once again .